# Heroku (Docker) PORT environment variable in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, heroku, dockerfile

I just take a few modifications on a Dockerfile to run it with nginx on Heroku. Something special about Heroku is, that everything is running as non-root. Second certain behaviour is the use of a random Port which comes from Heroku itself and you can't be modified. They provide the env $PORT which you should bind to nginx. If Heroku recognizes that something isn't bind to that port it stops the entire container. Question is:

How can I bind nginx to a given env variable in order to have a dynamic port in the nginx-site.conf?
I tried to use things like follows in the *Dockefile*:

`env PORT;` in *nginx.conf* and `listen PORT_from_env;` in the *nginx-site.conf*
Also tried `listen 80;` in the *nginx-site.conf* and `RUN /bin/sed -i "s/listen 80/listen ${PORT}/" /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf` in the *Dockerfile*

I am absolutely above my capabilities. Someone has an idea or can help? It be very helpful!

---

Further information:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos

Answer (score 18):

I got it working for my app by following [this example](https://github.com/rjoonas/heroku-docker-nginx-example) :

**Step 1:** listen to `$PORT` in `default.conf.template`

```
server {
  listen $PORT default_server;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** add this directive to your `Dockerfile`

```
COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
```

**Step 3:** add this at the **end** of your `Dockerfile`

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you my feedback by time. Will try it in the future again!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I'll show a solution which doesn't require to write a new Dockerfile, you can use the offical nginx images.

Like @Jimmy's solution we'll use the [envsubst](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html) command which substitutes environment variables in shell format strings. 
This command is available with the [offical nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and also with the alpine version.

**Step #1** 

write your nginx configuration in a template file - let's call it: `site.template`:

```
server {
    listen       ${PORT};
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Notice the PORT placeholder.

**Step #2 - with docker compose** 

Mount that inside the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory and then execute the `envsubst` command to use the template as a reference for `default.conf`:

```
web:
  image: nginx:alpine
  volumes:
   - ./site.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template
  ports:
   - "3000:8080"
  environment:
   - PORT=8080
  command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Notice that: 
 1. You need to execute the nginx daemon after that. 
 2. I used `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash` because my base image is alpine.

---

**Step #2 (Another option) - inline docker run** 

If, for some reason you don't want to work with docker-compose you can use the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##### Variables #####
PORT=8080 #Or $1 if you pass it from command line
TEMPLATE_DIR=$(pwd)/site.template
TEMPLATE_REMOTE_DIR=/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template
IMAGE_NAME=nginx:alpine

echo "Starting nginx on port: $PORT ..."

##### The docker command #####
docker run -p 3000:$PORT -v $TEMPLATE_DIR:$TEMPLATE_REMOTE_DIR $IMAGE_NAME \
/bin/sh -c "envsubst < $TEMPLATE_REMOTE_DIR > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your nginx configuration at boot time.
See [this buildpack](https://github.com/ngs/heroku-docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile#L133) as an example (I haven't tested that it does work).

Comment: That is what I am impled with `sed -i`. This happens at boot time and is the same as you suggested. Even the Dockerfile I know and considered in the past.