# Nginx - Heroku Docker - Is it possible to run Nginx as a reverse proxy on Heroku

Tags: docker, nginx, heroku, reverse-proxy, docker-container

I'm trying to figure out how build a reverse proxy on an Heroku app with Nginx. The problem is that Heroku seems to accept only one container per application. But my application system would use at least three container:

- one for Nginx
- one for my app frontend
- one for my business logic server

So is it possible to make that with Heroku?  I mean, deploy in a way or another a multi-container application on the same domain? It would be purely awesome. 
If someone has any hint, would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe on Heroku you have to set explicitly several application as different services ? Then the multiple app architecture would be appreciated as a core architecture design of the Herokuverse ?

Answer (score 12):

I have a template which is kind of similar, but difference is that it requires 3 applications in heroku.
Since each container runs in separate application, all of them are exposed to outer world.

This template uses travis to build and deploy containers to heroku.
Template has 3 images
* Frontend(Nginx - React)
* Backend(Nodejs - express)
* Server(Nginx)

I have referred below urls for my template.
https://medium.com/@javierfernandes/continuous-deployment-con-docker-travis-heroku-c24042fb830b
[Heroku (Docker) PORT environment varibale in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147389/heroku-docker-port-environment-varibale-in-nginx)

Below is repository url.
https://github.com/pramodramdas/heroku_multi_dockers

### Steps

- Create 3 applications in heroku.
- Get api key from heroku -> account settings -> Api Key
- Create following environment variables in travis

  HEROKU_USERNAME=_       //underscore
  HEROKU_PASSWORD=        //Api key from heroku
  HEROKU_API_KEY=         //same api key as above
  HEROKU_APP_BACKEND=     //heroku back end app name without ".herokuapp.com"
  HEROKU_APP_CLIENT=      //heroku front end app name without ".herokuapp.com"
  HEROKU_APP_NGINX=       //heroku nginx app name without ".herokuapp.com"
  DOCKER_USERNAME=        //dockerhub username
  DOCKER_PASSWORD=        //dockerhub password
- Create following environment variables in nginx heroku app

  HEROKU_APP_BACKEND_URL= //heroku back end app url example: xxxxxx.herokuapp.com
  HEROKU_APP_CLIENT_URL=  //heroku front end app url example: xxxxxx.herokuapp.com

My nginx server config.

```
upstream client {
  server $HEROKU_APP_CLIENT_URL;
}

upstream backend {
  server $HEROKU_APP_BACKEND_URL;
}

server {
  listen $PORT;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_set_header Host $HEROKU_APP_CLIENT_URL;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $HEROKU_APP_BACKEND_URL;
  }
}
```

front end bundle is severed through separate nginx server inside Frontend container. Below is config

```
server {
  listen $PORT;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Docker file should have commands to copy bundle to nginx and

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT \$HEROKU_APP_CLIENT_URL \$HEROKU_APP_BACKEND_URL' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

at end of docker file in order to pick env variables.

Below is travis config

```
sudo: required
language: node_js 
node_js: 
  - "9"
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
  - echo "$HEROKU_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$HEROKU_USERNAME" --password-stdin registry.heroku.com

script:
  - docker build -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_client ./frontend_heroku;
  - docker tag $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_client registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_CLIENT/web;
  - docker build -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_backend ./backend_heroku;
  - docker tag $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_backend registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_BACKEND/web;
  - docker build -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_nginx ./nginx_heroku;
  - docker tag $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_nginx registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NGINX/web;

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: 
    # push to dockerhub & heroku 
    docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_client;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_CLIENT/web;
    heroku container:release web --app $HEROKU_APP_CLIENT;
    docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_backend;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_BACKEND/web;
    heroku container:release web --app $HEROKU_APP_BACKEND;
    docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/docker_nginx;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NGINX/web;
    heroku container:release web --app $HEROKU_APP_NGINX;
  on: 
    branch: master
```

Comment: Three different applications? Would all there of them need to be scaled up to hobby or higher? Currently, the cheapest option for ONE non-free application is $7/month

Answer (score 1):

i am not writing anything new from @Pram, just what i had to do.

1. i had 1 frontend server (react built files being served by nginx server)
2. 1 backend server (ts-node)
3. reverse proxy (nginx server)

this resulted in 3 heroku apps.

1. all routes starting from /api go to backend.
2. all other routes go to frontend.
3. my authentication was "cookie based"

---

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
upstream frontend {
    server $FRONTEND_URL;
}

upstream backend {
    server $BACKEND_URL;
}

server {
    listen $PORT;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $FRONTEND_URL;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $BACKEND_URL;
        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
    }

}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT \$FRONTEND_URL \$BACKEND_URL' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

[full code](https://github.com/shameekagarwal/gql)