# Get the certificate and key file names stored on Heroku to set up SSL on Nginx server

Tags: nginx, heroku, ssl-certificate, private-key

I wanted to add the certificate and key to the Nginx server that my application is served on and hosted by Heroku. This is what I currently have in my Nginx config file. Does proxying the SSL server work for this instead and keeps the server secure? If not then how am I supposed to get file names for the `.pem` and `.key` files that I uploaded to Heroku for my specific application?

nginx.conf.erb

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type text/html;

    sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

    #Must read the body in 65 seconds.
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # handle SNI
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;

        # Define the specified charset to the “Content-Type” response header field
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            proxy_ssl_name <%= ENV["HEROKU_DOMAIN"] %>;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /app/flask_app/static;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you can, TLS is probably terminated at the router so your app doesn't have to know about it.

Comment: I have my web app served through Nginx and I'm pretty sure I need to state where the SSL key and certificate can be found (according to https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/nginx-openssl.htm#ssl_certificate_install). Do I need to specify the key and certificate for Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create SSL certificate from CloudFlare, you can't access through Heroku CLI, but you can download it through CloudFlare.

1. Please check if you have routed your domain web through [Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS).
2. Download the SSL Cert via CloudFlare.
3. Setup SSL cert for Nginx [Setup SSL Cert](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-using-cloudflare-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

1. Put SSL cert `.key` and `.pem` into same folder with `nginx.conf.erb`. I.e. `domain_name.key` & `domain_name.pem`
2. Deploy to Heroku.
3. Use config like this:

```
ssl_certificate domain_name.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  domain_name.key;
```

Comment: The Nginx server is set up through Heroku so like I said above in my comments, I dont know where Heroku stores the key and certificate files I uploaded to an application so I'm not sure what the correct file path is for both of these files. The documentation you posted says that I need to have the file paths in the Nginx config file under the server object.

Comment: In the documentation to set up the SSL certificate for Nginx, it says I need these two lines of code `ssl_certificate   /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.pem; (or bundle.crt)
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.key;` Since I copied and pasted my certificate and key to Heroku, I have no idea if my domain name will be the file name for both the `.pem` and `.key` files on Heroku's environment. Will they be?

Comment: Hi, I'll try to check on this issue, never been a fan on combining heroku and nginx. 

Meanwhile, check this links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725264/6118551 and https://help.heroku.com/YTWRHLVH/how-do-i-make-my-nginx-proxy-connect-to-a-heroku-app-behind-heroku-ssl.

Comment: Oh and heroku has different method to expose SSL. The cert must be installed using heroku cli or on their web. I don't think you have to configure it inside nginx unless you use docker as container.

Comment: I chose to combine Nginx with Heroku because I read that Nginx serves static files to clients faster than over gunicorn. Also, I want to set up an RTMP server to be processed through the backend, and Nginx has that capability. I think I am going to need to use docker eventually in order to set up the RTMP server correctly.

Comment: Yes, I did add it on Heroku's website (same as installing through their CLI), but I just wanted to make sure that I secured the Nginx server as well.

Comment: A little weird but I'm sure you know what you're doing. After I've checked this repo, https://github.com/narr/heroku-nginx-node-example/tree/master/config, I assume you can put SSL certificate in the same folder with `nginx.conf.erb`. Check my update post.

Comment: If you look at the config file I posted in my question, I have the `proxy_ssl_name on;` which enables SNI and in the `/` location of the server it sets the `proxy_ssl_name <%= ENV["HEROKU_DOMAIN"] %>;` I have the `HEROKU_DOMAIN` key-value pair stored as a config variable on Heroku's site for my app. The value for that key is `example.com`. Is what I have enough to secure the server without stating the certificate and key used to sign the certificate?